# Python module is not supported in android studio using chaquopy

Tags: python, android, chaquopy, android-studio-4.1

In my project I am trying to integrate the python into android studio using chaquopy. My android version is 4.1.1, chaquopy version is 9.1.0 and python version 3.8.6.  In android studio, I have created a python folder and in it I have written python code where the android compiler is showing error in "import". I have attached the snapshot.
[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMAwU.png)

[python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnrbk.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to explain the question in detail on the main part itself. Please post your research on the same with the script/code/images along with the difficulty you face. To get a clear idea of how to ask a question.See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score -1):

This is explained in [the documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-studio-plugin):

> To add Python editing suppport to the Android Studio user interface, you may optionally install the “Python Community Edition” plugin. However, Chaquopy isn’t integrated with this plugin, so you’ll see the warning “No Python interpreter configured for the module”, and your code will probably display many error indicators such as “Unresolved reference” and “No module named”. These are harmless: just go ahead and run your app, and if there really is an error, the details will be displayed in the Logcat.

Comment: Python Community Edition Plugin is already there but still the application gets crashed when it is launching and in logcat it displays no python module find and a error line is displayed in the each and every line of import statement in python file

Comment: Like I said, the errors displayed in Android Studio are usually harmless. The important error is the one in the Logcat, so please edit your question with the "Edit" link above to include the complete text of that error. It would also be helpful if you include the relevant lines of your source code.